# cpprestsdk post request thru Postman return status code 500

Tags: c++, postman, cpprest-sdk

I have server with code from this [example](https://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2017/11/19/revisited-full-fledged-client-server-example-with-c-rest-sdk-2-10/)

When i trying to send post (or get,put,del) request thru Postman i got 500 server code responce(Internal error), what can cause the problem

```
#include <cpprest/http_listener.h>
#include <cpprest/json.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "cpprest_2_10")

using namespace web;
using namespace web::http;
using namespace web::http::experimental::listener;

#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void handle_request(
    http_request request,
    function<void(json::value&)> action)
{
    auto answer = json::value::object();

    request
        .extract_json()
        .then([&answer, &action](pplx::task<json::value> task) {
        try
        {
            auto const& jvalue = task.get();
            wcout << answer.serialize() << endl;

            if (!jvalue.is_null())
            {
                action( answer);
            } 
        }
        catch (http_exception const& e)
        {
            wcout << e.what() << endl;
        }
            })
        .wait();

            wcout << answer.serialize() << endl;
            request.reply(status_codes::OK, answer);
}

void handle_post(http_request request)
{
    std::cout << "Something received" << std::endl;

    handle_request(
        request,
        [](json::value& answer)
        {
            answer[L"random"] = json::value::string(L"success");
        });
}



int main()
{
    http_listener listener(L"http://localhost/restdemo");

    listener.support(methods::POST, handle_post);
    try
    {
        listener
            .open()
            .then([&listener]() { std::cout << "LISTENING" << std::endl; })
            .wait();

        while (true);
    }
    catch (exception const& e)
    {
        wcout << e.what() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is my minimal reproduceble example, and when i post requesting in Postman, on the server side i see only "Something received" line.

I test out that server go wrong on line

```
auto const& jvalue = task.get();
```

Debug line working before and not working after that line.

[image: Postman settings]

[image: Postman body]

Comment: Wouldn't your HTTP server log an error in addition to returning a 500 error? If not you need to bump the logging.

Comment: @Botje I dont realy know how to get log from the ccprestsdk. Can you explain how to do it ?

Comment: I briefly checked that library and it does not do any logging at all. That is annoying. Suggest you post a [mre] of your code for the specific endpoint that fails. You should also put a debug breakpoint on the few lines that create an `InternalError` response.

Comment: @Botje I edit my qwestion with minimal reproduceble code. What you think ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: @Botje I found out line where server go bad its "auto const& jvalue = task.get();"

Comment: That means it threw an exception which you should have caught and printed. Also, can you show the exact request you are sending via postman?

Comment: @Botje Added the postman body and settings

Comment: There's your problem. You're sending a form-data encoded body instead of actual JSON. I think you can do this by choosing the "raw" type and then selecting the json format.

Comment: @Botje This is it i made json as row data and voila! works well ! Thank you so much mate! How can i like your question, with addition to your carma ?

Comment: This question is not terribly useful for future searchers as you basically gave the wrong input. You can pay it forward by making your next question clearer and including all necessary information up front.

Comment: @Botje Ok, thanks for all of your advices !

Answer (score 0):

My error was in that, i tried to request content-type json/application thru postman form-data encoding , when i form json in raw section it works. All credits for answer goes to @Botje!